# If I open and read the file which is periodically written, can I/O deadlock occur?

Tags: python, linux, performance, io, deadlock

In my server process, it looks like this:

Main backend processes:

1. Processes Huge list of files and , record them inside MySQL.
2. On every 500 files done, it writes "Progress Report" to a separate file `/var/run/progress.log` like this "200/5000 files done"
3. It is multi-processed with 4 children, each made sure to run on a separate file.

Web server process:

1. Read the output of `/var/run/progress.log` every 10 seconds via Ajax and report to progress bar.

When processing a very large list of files (e.g. over 3 GB archive), the processes lock up after about 2 hours of processing.

I can't find what is going on. Does that mean that `/var/run/progress.log` caused an I/O deadlock?

Comment: Do you fill '/var/run/progress.log' file by yourself or use some standard logging module?

Comment: By my self , but writes are always closed immediately. They are like write every 3-5 second , depending on size of file .

Comment: Unless you use file locks, there's no such thing as  I/O deadlocking - it's a bug in your program somewhere. run `strace -p` on the process to see what it's trying to do.

Comment: lets say , While a process open a file  and writing data into it, and then another file tries to read (that open one is not closed) wont it cause IO Slowdown / Lockup?

Comment: No, it won't deadlock. However, your reading application could read a partial update. If your parsing code isn't written to expect invalid data, you could have an exception being through from an unexpected place. Depending on your code structure, that could easily cause the appearance of a 'deadlock'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python on Linux this should not block, however try using the `os` module

```
os.open(file, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
```

and make sure you close the file `fh.close()` as Python is a bit lazy clean up files.

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick advice, make sure (like, super sure) that you do close your file.

So ALWAYS use a try-except-final block for this

Remember that the contens of a final block will ALWAYS be executed, that will prevent you a lot of head pain :)